# How to attach a zip file and Upload it to a REST service with PUT method using mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Below is my code, I have used a mule requester to read the zip file an dthen I have used an attachment component and given the value as #[payload], and content type as multipart/x-zip but some how it is not working. can anyone please help me.

```
        <mulerequester:request  resource="file://src/test/resources/test/test.jpg?connector=File" 
doc:name="Retrieve File"  config-ref="Mule_Requester"/>
    <set-attachment attachmentName="test" value="#[payload]" contentType="multipart/x-zip" doc:name="Attachment"/>

    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_RequestUpload_Configuration2" path="/dmf/projectname123_n1_1wer?sv=2014-02-14&amp;sr=b&amp;sig=AV2pJHnP4Zf%2Bk5wTX%2FuNnoBKOqyiIZhh8N%2BbsVNzJ18%3D&amp;st=2018-03-09T18%3A56%3A23Z&amp;se=2018-03-09T19%3A11%3A23Z&amp;sp=rw" method="PUT" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="x-ms-blob-type" value="BlockBlob"/>
            <http:header headerName="x-ms-version" value="2015-02-21"/>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/octet-stream"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
    <flow-ref name="importExecutionIdFlow" doc:name=""/>
</flow>
```

Comment: "It is not working". It is a good idea to be as specific as possible about the problems you are having, and the behaviour you observe.

Comment: hi  Jdv, I am facing time out error, when I give the value as #[payload] in the attachment component, but when I give some string instead of payload it is working. and the output from the mule requester is "org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$7@1fde08a2"

Comment: [edit] your question and put those details there instead. Comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use Attachment component before http-request and select the Content Type as application/zip. The payload taken by the Attachment component will be generated as a zip attachment

Answer (score -1):

Retrive the zip file using the groovy script transformer.

```
def retrieve_zipFile = payload.retrieve_zipFile;
message.setInvocationProperty("retrieve_zipFile", retrieve_zipFile);
```

In set_attachment,you can access the file using `#[flowVars.retrieve_zipFile]` and select the content type as multipart/x-zip

Comment: I am using mule requester , can I give the groovy component after the mule requester with your code will this work then??